# HMAC SHA512 using CommonCrypto in Swift 3.1

Tags: swift, xcode, hmac, sha512, commoncrypto

I'm trying to encrypt data to send to the API.

The API requires the data to be sent as `hmac_sha512` encrypted hash.

I've found various examples of how it possibly could have been done for `sha1` and others (not `sha512`) and also in older versions of Swift.

None of the examples that I tried work for `swift 3.1`

Any help in the right direction will be appreciated.

**Edit:**

In PHP, I successfully send it using:

```
    $sign = hash_hmac('sha512', $post_data, $this->secret);
```

**Edit 2:**

I `did add briding header`, I don't know what to do next! As the code examples followed after that don't work for swift 3.1 :(

**Edit 3:**

**Solved!** Guess what, I was creating briding header incorrectly! :(

P.S I'm trying to **avoid CryptoSwift, focusing on CommonCrypto.**

The answer given below is not proper, as it doesn't allow hmac to get a key for encryption. I did research and finally got it working. This post contains the working example project for hmac: https://github.com/nabtron/hmacTest

Comment: you can't send data as a hash... are you sending a signature or do they want it sha512 encrypted ?

Comment: in php i use:         $sign = hash_hmac('sha512', $post_data, $this->secret);

Comment: See answer [Swift HMAC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46282026/451475).

Answer (score 6):

I think the best thing to do is using [Crypto](https://github.com/soffes/Crypto) pod which is a wrapper for common crypto. In case you want to use directly commonCrypto you should add the bridging header to the project and import common crypto using: `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>`

**Edit 1**

Create a swift class and add the following code to it:

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    var md5: String {
        return HMAC.hash(inp: self, algo: HMACAlgo.MD5)
    }

    var sha1: String {
        return HMAC.hash(inp: self, algo: HMACAlgo.SHA1)
    }

    var sha224: String {
        return HMAC.hash(inp: self, algo: HMACAlgo.SHA224)
    }

    var sha256: String {
        return HMAC.hash(inp: self, algo: HMACAlgo.SHA256)
    }

    var sha384: String {
        return HMAC.hash(inp: self, algo: HMACAlgo.SHA384)
    }

    var sha512: String {
        return HMAC.hash(inp: self, algo: HMACAlgo.SHA512)
    }
}

public struct HMAC {

    static func hash(inp: String, algo: HMACAlgo) -> String {
        if let stringData = inp.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
            return hexStringFromData(input: digest(input: stringData as NSData, algo: algo))
        }
        return ""
    }

    private static func digest(input : NSData, algo: HMACAlgo) -> NSData {
        let digestLength = algo.digestLength()
        var hash = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: digestLength)
        switch algo {
        case .MD5:
            CC_MD5(input.bytes, UInt32(input.length), &hash)
            break
        case .SHA1:
            CC_SHA1(input.bytes, UInt32(input.length), &hash)
            break
        case .SHA224:
            CC_SHA224(input.bytes, UInt32(input.length), &hash)
            break
        case .SHA256:
            CC_SHA256(input.bytes, UInt32(input.length), &hash)
            break
        case .SHA384:
            CC_SHA384(input.bytes, UInt32(input.length), &hash)
            break
        case .SHA512:
            CC_SHA512(input.bytes, UInt32(input.length), &hash)
            break
        }
        return NSData(bytes: hash, length: digestLength)
    }

    private static func hexStringFromData(input: NSData) -> String {
        var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: input.length)
        input.getBytes(&bytes, length: input.length)

        var hexString = ""
        for byte in bytes {
            hexString += String(format:"%02x", UInt8(byte))
        }

        return hexString
    }
}

enum HMACAlgo {
    case MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512

    func digestLength() -> Int {
        var result: CInt = 0
        switch self {
        case .MD5:
            result = CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA1:
            result = CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA224:
            result = CC_SHA224_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA256:
            result = CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA384:
            result = CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA512:
            result = CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH
        }
        return Int(result)
    }
}
```

then use it simply by `stringName.sha512`
this class extends the String class which gives the ability to use the hashing as a function in the string class.

Comment: i did add briding header, I don't know what to do next!

Comment: check the edit and contact me for help!

Comment: it gives errors like: "use of unresolved identifier CC_MD5" and so on :(

Comment: **Solved!** Guess what, I was creating briding header incorrectly! :(

Comment: how can i pass the string and secret key both to it? like the PHP example above?